# Python os.walk + follow symlinks

Tags: python, symlink, traversal, directory-traversal, symlink-traversal

How do I get this piece to follow symlinks in python 2.6?

```
def load_recursive(self, path):
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.xml'):
                file_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
                try:
                    do_stuff(file_path) 
                except:
                    continue
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Set `followlinks` to `True`. This is the fourth argument to the `os.walk` method, reproduced below:

```
os.walk(top[, topdown=True[, onerror=None[, followlinks=False]]])
```

This option was added in Python 2.6.

**EDIT 1**

Be careful when using `followlinks=True`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

> **Note:** Be aware that setting `followlinks` to True can lead to
> infinite recursion if a link points to a parent directory of itself.
> walk() does not keep track of the directories it visited already.

Comment: Thank you, `os.walk(path, followlinks=True):` did the trick, although Python documentation was quite unclear about this: http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.walk

Comment: @Frank: of course it was unclear; you're looking at the documentation for `os.path.walk` which is a separate (older and deprecated) function. You should be looking at the [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) documentation.